# dynamic expandable form on input text field change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to build a expandable form when ever the someone enter text into input field. Example user fills the location a form expands below the input fields which asks for check-in/checkout dates.

or like in gmail when you enter the search string and click on the arrow it opens the advanced search form. I have attached a screen shot on the same.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input id="geocomplete"  style="width:200px;" type="text" placeholder="Type in an address" size="90" autocomplete="on">    

<div id="checkInOutDiv" class="hiddenDiv">
    <input id="checkInDate" type="text" />
    <input id="checkOutDate" type="text" />    
</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.hiddenDiv {
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var defaultAddrText = $("#geocomplete").attr("placeholder");
        $("#geocomplete").keydown(function(){//could be 'onchange' instead
            var addr = $(this).val();
            if( addr != '' && addr != defaultAddrText ){
                $("#checkInOutDiv").removeClass("hiddenDiv");    
            }else{
                $("#checkInOutDiv").addClass("hiddenDiv");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have added a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranphp5/6Z93b/3/, I want that when user fills the address in the form, it should ask for check-in and check-out dates by expanding the input box.

Comment: @user3303048 I updated my answer. Make sure to surround JS and CSS in appropriate tags - <script> and <style> when you do it outside of fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for this, but my real issue was opening a dropdown box like in gmail, which is like a slider box that opens up once the location input is submitted. Could you suggest me how i do that, else is there any jquery plugin that can help me build that sliding form http://jsfiddle.net/kiranphp5/6Z93b/4/

Comment: @user3303048 I don't quite get what you're asking for. Are you looking for date picker code? http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: This is resolved now, I could place a form inside a menu dropdown div and achive what I wanted. Thanks for your help.